# BluemixのNode-REDでTwitter連携の設定ができません。

Tags: bluemix, twitter

BlueMixのNode-REDを使って、Twitter連携の設定ができなくて困ってます。
Twitterの設定を何度見直して試してももできません。お解かりになる方、教えていただけますでしょうか？

[image: 鉛筆マークをクリック]
[image: 認証成功が表示されます]
Twitterでの認証は成功してますが、鉛筆マークの画面から変わりません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

解決しました。

Windows10を使用しているため、ブラウザーはIE11,Edgeを使用して操作をしていました。
Chromeを使ったら解決しました。

ありがとうございました。